# Is it safe to pass GCM registration ID to partner servers

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

We have an Android app which we would like to allow multiple (between 50-100) third parties to send push notifications to the app.

So if the app user imports content from one or more third parties, then they can receive push notifications from those third parties.

We thought we could do this by creating a GCM API key for each of the third parties, and then when the content is imported we would pass the GCM registration ID to the third party's server (the URL of this server is included in the content).

However, we see this in the documentation; "Note that registration tokens must be kept secret." (https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm#senderid).

In theory, users could import content from a non-partnered third party, at which point they'd get the GCM registration ID passed to them. This could obviously be stopped by performing a lookup so we only pass the GCM registration ID to known third parties.

The push notification is then handled within the app so that only the third parties content is effected, so that's not really a concern (plus we could revoke the API key of any third parties that abuse it by spamming too many updates, etc.).

Why do you need to keep the registration ID secret when only servers with the API key can do anything with it?

And is it a concern in the above scenario? i.e. is passing it to known third parties considered keeping it secret?

**Note; we've considered having all the third parties send a message to our server and then have us pass that message onto the app via GCM. But we'd ideally like to avoid having that dependency.**

---

Following the points raised by [deadlydragon00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3087778/deadlydragon00):

- We don't have any paid services active on the Google account. So there's no risk of the third party partners running up a bill using the supplied API key.
- Obviously over use of the push notifications is a concern, but as the third party partners can only use this to effect their content in our app, this would reflect badly on them, so we don't see that as a huge concern (plus we'd give each third party their own API key, so could simply cut off access to anyone who does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution to consider would be to use [multiple senders](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server#multi-senders).

> To make this possible, all you need to do is have each sender generate its own project number. Then include those IDs in the sender field, separated by commas, when requesting a registration.

Comment: That seems ideal. Can't believe I never saw that when searching through the docs!

Answer (score -1):

> Why do you need to keep the registration ID secret when only servers
>   with the API key can do anything with it?

What if you subscribe for any paid Google service like Appengine then you gave your RegID to someone that can abuse it like flooding multiple request, now look at your billing.

> And is it a concern in the above scenario? i.e. is passing it to known
>   third parties considered keeping it secret?

Again do not give it.

you can follow this flow if you want to keep your regID as secret as possible
[image]

The figure above shows that

1. The third party should send the message to your server (Don't send directly to the App) In this case you do not need to expose your RegID.
2. The information/Data will be analyze and send to the app.

Comment: "Note; we've considered having all the third parties send a message to our server and then have us pass that message onto the app via GCM. But we'd ideally like to avoid having that dependency." - we considered your proposed solution (as mentioned in the post) and we're looking for a solution that doesn't rely on us maintaining a server.

Comment: We also don't have any other APIs enabled on that Google account. So is the risk of the 3rd parties using paid APIs the only reason not to give them an API key and pass on the registration ID?

Comment: @AndyNugent if someone knows your GCM id they might spam you with false request, Google will surely send you a Note telling your abusing the service and it might lead to a temporary suspension of using this service. Basically there is no better solution aside from setting up your own Middle-Man server.

Comment: If you go for the easy way well its a trap.

Comment: So the only issue you can think of is that the third parties may overuse the system, which we would be able to monitor and revoke the API key in question? We understand that a central server is the normal/obvious solution, but it's not ideal in this situation, which is why I'm asking the question.

Comment: I could not suggest any further *but yes they might overuse it*, Google also suggest this approach so I have no doubt that this is the best way to deal with it. It might not suits to your need or specification but we have no full control over Google Service but then again you have a full control to your thirdparties.